# Bash : Adding input file names in output results

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I'm using cURL API to submit files on a API service and It returns back with something called `taks_id` for the files submitted.

```
#submitter.sh

creation_date=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
task_id_file="/home/results/$creation_date"_task_ids".csv"
for i in $(find $1  -type f);do
        task_id="$(curl -s -F file=@$i http://X.X.X.X:XXXX/api/tiscale/v1/upload)"
        final_task_id=$(echo $task_id | grep -o 'http\?://[^"]\+')
        echo "$final_task_id" >> $task_id_file
done 

#Result ( 10_13_2016_task_ids.csv )

http://192.168.122.24:8080/api/tiscale/v1/task/17
http://192.168.122.24:8080/api/tiscale/v1/task/18
http://192.168.122.24:8080/api/tiscale/v1/task/19
```

Run Method :

```
$./submitter.sh /home/files/pdf/
```

Now, Using[find $1  -type f] logic will get the full path with file name mentioned.

```
#find /home/files/pdf -type f 

/home/files/pdf/country.pdf
/home/files/pdf/summary.pdf
/home/files/pdf/age.pdf
```

How can i add the file names along with cURL API response result. For example , When submitting `"/home/files/country.pdf"`, The API might give the task_id with `http://192.168.122.24:8080/api/tiscale/v1/task/`17'`.

Expecting Result :

```
country.pdf,http://192.168.122.24:8080/api/tiscale/v1/task/17
summary.pdf,http://192.168.122.24:8080/api/tiscale/v1/task/18
age.pdf,http://192.168.122.24:8080/api/tiscale/v1/task/19
```

I'm beginner in Bash, Any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

Comment: echo "$(basename "$i"),$final_task_id" >> $task_id_file

Comment: BTW, your script contains several problems - make a habit checking your shell scripts with `shellcheck` (it is also available online at http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: @Leon Yes, I've checked it . Thanks , Will change the way i write in coming days.